# Taking JSON values in a response and mapping them to a state object with keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Noob to Javascript and React] I am using an API that returns an object with values like this. AAPL, AMZN, FB, GOOGL, can be anything based on the function's string array input.

```
{
        AAPL: { price: 329.99 },
        AMZN: { price: 2563.05 },
        FB: { price: 239.93 },
        GOOGL: { price: 1469.12 }
}
```

How could I consider dynamically mapping a response like this into a state object like this? The id property doesn't exist, it needs to be created.

```
state = {
 stocks: [ { id: 1, name: 'AAPL', price: 329.99 }, { id: 2, name: 'AMZN', price: 2563.05 }, ...]
}
```

I'm able to successfully print the stock names and their prices separately but I am having trouble figuring out how I could wire them into a state object like what's above.

```
    function getCurrentPriceOfBatchStocks(_stocks) {
        iex
            .symbols(_stocks)
            .price()
            .then(res => {
                console.log(typeof res);
                console.log(res);
                console.log(Object.keys(res));
                console.log(Object.values(res));
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation. With Object.entries, you get an array with an array of [key, value] of your original object. And you can map this array to a different format.

You can check the result with the `Run code snippet` button.

```js
let st = {
    AAPL: { price: 329.99 },
    AMZN: { price: 2563.05 },
    FB: { price: 239.93 },
    GOOGL: { price: 1469.12 }
}

let stocks = Object.entries(st).map(([key, value], index) => ({id: index + 1, name: key, price: value.price}))

console.log(stocks)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Do you know of a good doc page about this mapping syntax I can read to understand it better? I want to get better at mapping different object formats / structures like this. 
```Object.entries(st).map(([key, value], index)```

Comment: I think the mozilla page is the starting point in javascript. This is the map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: This is the Object.entries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you're getting id from, so I'm using idx as an example.

```
const stocks = Object.keys(resp).map((key, idx) => ({ id: idx + 1, name: key, price: resp[key] }))
```

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, id doesn't exist, I want to create that pair for each array entry and increment it.

Comment: That's basically what using `idx` here does.

Comment: Ah okay. This is close but the price value is being created as an object: ```1: {id: 2, name: "AMZN", price: {…}}```

Comment: What's used to map `resp` here, should be the object that contains your `AAPL`, `AMZN` etc. keys.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const res={
        AAPL: { price: 329.99 },
        AMZN: { price: 2563.05 },
        FB: { price: 239.93 },
        GOOGL: { price: 1469.12 }
}

console.log(Object.entries(res).map((entry,index)=>{
return {
  id:index+1,
  name:entry[0],
...entry[1]
  }
}));
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Do you know of any good documentation that helped you understand this mapping syntax better? I want to understand and know it better so I can get comfortable with mapping different object structures.